# Control of flow of current usig Tri-state buffers

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor

Are Tri-state buffers essential to the building of processors?
If we connect the control input of the Tri-state buffer to the Q or Q bar of a flip flop then we can program?

Comment: no, you can build a processor without them

Comment: Not essential, but makes certain parts easier to make such as a bi-directional data bus.